# How to go back to last page viewed in Document Viewer?

Tags: pdf

Say I have a 1000 page PDF document. I'm viewing something on page 100 and need to check something on page 944. Now I'm on page 944 and want to jump back to my last viewed page 100. How would I do that? From most windows pdf programms I'm used to something like `Control`+(`<-` or `->`). But that doesn't seem to work in Ubuntu PDF Viewer.

I also tried combinations of `Control`, `Shift` and `Alt`.

Comment: In the top bar of the viewer there is an icon with a spanner which takes you to View Options. In the list of options is Previous Page

Comment: If you **know** the page you want to go to, press `Ctrl+L`, enter the page number and press `enter`.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (previous) and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> (next) are the shortcuts you are looking for. You can see all available keyboard combinations under the menu (tree vertical dots).

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Maybe there is some config that automatically creates and deletes bookmarks? I was looking around for that but couldn't find it... Maybe there is a config file somewhere?

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 19.10 (Evince 3.34.1)